# How to return the rows that has in main table but not other table

Tags: sql-server

I am having External_Blk_Itm_Contracts table which has terminalId and CustomerId

And I also have budcontract table which has also columns terminalId and CustomerId

Now how to get all those records which are not in budcontract table based on terminalId and CustomerId.

Let’s say if terminalid = 76 and customerid = 25. If this combination already there in budcontracts table then External_Blk_Itm_Contracts should not return that result, if the combination is something different like terminalid = 77 and customerid = 25. Which has only in External_Blk_Itm_Contracts but not in budcontract table then it should return that result

How to write query for this

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get records from one table that don't exist in another table? You can do this through a join:

```
SELECT t1.terminalId, t1.CustomerId
FROM External_Blk_Itm_Contracts t1
LEFT JOIN CustomerId t2 ON t1.terminalId = t2.terminalId
AND t1.CustomerId = t2.CustomerId
WHERE t2.terminalId IS NULL AND t2.CustomerId IS NULL
```

Comment: doesnt work you are just doing self join but i have 3 tables here

Comment: @user1030181 that isn't a self join. A self join is a query that pulls from one and then joins to the same table.